# Force app interface style in Xcode UI tests with iOS target to be light or dark

Tags: ios, xcuitest

In my UI test I'm trying to force the app's user interface style to be light or dark. On macOS, when the system appearance is light, I can force the app to be dark with this code:

```
var app = XCUIApplication()
app.launchArguments += ["-AppleInterfaceStyle", "Dark"]
app.launch()
```

Sadly, this doesn't work with a iOS target, and `UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle` is read-only. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scanning through the documentation I see [`XCUIDevice`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuidevice) has an [`appearance`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuidevice/4108227-appearance) property.

Try this:

```
XCUIDevice.shared.appearance = .dark // or .light
```

This requires Xcode 14.3 or later according to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuidevice/4108227-appearance).

Comment: Did Apple change the API?  Why am I getting *Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'light'* and *Value of type 'XCUIDevice' has no member 'appearance'* while the docs sayin the contrary? Do anyone has any clue about this?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using on which macOS version?

Comment: @Kozmotronik You need Xcode 14.3 or later to use the code in my answer.

Comment: macOS Monterey 12.6.9, XCode 14.2.